# Autocomplete/Suggestions working in vscode but not in Intellij

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellij-idea, material-ui

I have a custom library that I documented extensively (as in PropTypes). All my custom components are derived from Material-UI components.

`@myModule/dist/myComponent/MyComponent` is imported in another react project and its documentation looks something like this.

```
Component.propTypes = {
/**
 * The children are the content.
 * Nest children between the opening and closing tags
 * instead of passing them as children={<div />}
 * @type node
 * @default <div />
 */
children: PropTypes.node,

/**
 * Title of the dialog
 * @type string
 */
title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
...
};
```

If I press CTRL+SPACE in vscode, the suggestion menu pops up and I can see all unused props.

[image]

If I hover on a prop, it shows me the documenation above.

[image]

However, if I open the same project in Intellij, no documentation/autocomplete is provided.

[image]

[image]

I am running Intellij Build #IU-223.7571.182 2022.3 Ultimate Edition. I also haven't changed any settings.

Any ideas what the culprit could be? Do I need a plugin?

EDIT: The components are exported via `npm run build` to the `dist` folder. Intellisense works if I use components from the `src` folder. But it fails if I import them from `modules/myModule/dist/MyComponent`.

The hierarchy in my library looks like this:
`components/someComponent/index.js`
I also tried renaming the component to `SomeComponent.js` and `SomeComponent.jsx`.

If I hover on the properties in the `node_modules/@xyz/myPackage/dist/myComponent/index.js` where my package was installed it shows me the documentation perfectly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

And this is how my documentation looks like if I CTRL+CLICK on one of my components from `node_modules`

[image]

EDIT: works for some props.

[image]

Comment: make sure that the `dist` folder is not excluded from indexing

Comment: Hey! Thanks for replying! Could you tell me how to check if it's indexing the dist folder?

Comment: I can see when I launch Intellij that it does index my `node_modules` folder where my installed library is. Sadly it does nothing.

Comment: I reindexed the library by right clicking on the folder in `node_modules` and then `Repair IDE on File` but it didn't help.

Comment: see what color it appears with in the project explorer or the Project Structure dialog

Comment: It does have a different color - I added a screenshot above - it's from the project where the library was installed.

Comment: you are using a custom color theme, so it's not quite clear what these colors mean. Please check the **Mark directory as** action in the folder right-click menu - what items can you see there? Also, is it a folder in `node_modules`, or your local project folder?

Comment: Hey @lena ! Sorry for taking a while - I have disabled all custom colors and updated the question with screenshots. It is a folder under `node_modules` - it is also a library I have built with `npm run build` and installed from `gitlab`

Comment: the `dist` folder and subfolders are marked excluded; please try un-excluding it

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the quick response. Looks like it worked - funnily though not every prop has documentation.

Comment: If the props are already set and I click on one of them and press CTRL+SPACE it displays the prop name and if I press on "Quick Documentation" it just displays the propName?: any. If there are no props set, the documentation is shown if I press on "Quick Documentation" (CTRL+G)